# Can Facebook block embedded links on my website

Tags: facebook

I wanted to know whether facebook had the ability to block a person's website from having embedded links. I don't know exactly how embeded links work, but as it is a generic link and no access is needed to actually implement an embed, it makes me wonder if facebook can block specific websites from using embedded links?

Also what can Facebook (or other social media giants) track on my website if it has embedded links?

Comment: What do you mean by embedded link? Are you talking about one of Facebook’s social plugins?

Comment: So simply if I want to copy a post from Facebook I can click embed link on the Facebook post and that post shows on my website when I put in the embedded link in the html. Not sure if that counts as on of Facebook’s social plugins?

Comment: So that would be the Embedded Posts plugin then. When you are using the JS version of this, then Facebook’s JavaScript code runs in the context of your site, so they can easily read which domain this is on, and then make the script refuse to do its job, if they wanted to. If you used the iframe version, then its gonna be a bit harder, they would have to rely on the visitors browser sending a correct referrer then.

Comment: Ahh yea I use the JS version to embed posts, yea that makes sense thanks alot CBroe!